# Will this Database design logic work?

Tags: database-design

I am currently working on structuring out a database in MySQL Workbench to keep track of expenses for Truck drivers that would be turned into an application using Java.

- Objective:

  ```
  Create a report of expenses in a table format
  View or Edit past expenses
  Display data Yearly report
          Total Company Salary
          Total Gas Expense
          Total Toll Expense
          Total Miscellaneous Expense
  ```
- Input Needed:

  ```
  Enter the Company Income earned weekly
  Enter the Gas Expense weekly
  Enter Toll Expense Weekly
  Enter Miscellaneous expense weekly
          Create a Miscellaneous category
  ```
- Calculation:

  ```
  Get Personal Salary = 
          Company Income - (Gas Expense + Toll Expense + Miscellaneous Expense)
  ```
- Result:

  ```
  Display information in a table
  ```

Right now the issue is structuring out MySQL tables.
Currently I have:
[image]

The portion of the results and calculations will be done in Java but I would like to know if this table structure is correct? I also want the user to input the type of miscellaneous expense.

Comment: For a simple basic app, your table structures **seem** fine - I put "seem" like that because it's **very** difficult to predict all system requirements in advance. What normally happens is that system design is an **iterative** process until it reaches some form of stability and is subsequently **tweaked** rather than redesigned (longest period of an apps lifetime). One thing does jump out at me though is that you should have categories  of miscellaneous expenses - "puncture", "vandalism", "theft", "chip butties"....&c.

Comment: @Vérace What i wanted to do was have the user add the name of the miscellaneous expense. So that way they can have their own categories. Since not every driver might have the save miscellaneous expense. Or is that not correct to do?

Comment: Absolutely **not**! Letting end-users enter their own categories via free text is a recipe for disaster! Spellings, hyphens, spaces, slang, foreign drivers - all will contribute towards upwards of 10 names for essentially the same thing! Poll your drivers and get the top, say, 20 categories. Then have a business process for adding them - even it's only a simple email/text or whatever, but free text - no!

Comment: @Vérace Thanks so much makes sense!

Comment: p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with this design.

1. Your link between users and expenses is around the wrong way. As it is designed, a single expense record can have multiple users. This should be a single user can have multiple expense records. Remove expense_id from users and add user_id to expenses (with related foreign keys).
2. You're going to end up with many NULL values in your expenses table and it will be a pain to query for analysis because of this, you will end up having to coalesce fields for any analysis of total expenses rather than individual expense types. Instead of having separate columns for the gas expense, toll expense and misc expense, have a single expense_value field and create an expense_type field linking to an expense_type lookup table that contains gas, toll and miscellaneous as records
3. Your personal_salary field should not be an attribute of an expense record, it should be an attribute of the user record. Again, you'll be storing this data repeatedly for no reason. Imagine if you were asked to provide a report on personal salaries only - do you want to query thousands of expense records or a few dozen employee records?
4. As above but with company_income, this should be an attribute of a company record, not an expense record.

NOTE: With points 3 & 4 above, if personal salary and company income are not annual/on-going static values but are instead values for a specific project or contract then these should still not be stored with expenses. Create a new table for Project/Contract, add a foreign key referencing a project/contract to the expense table and do it that way.

Also, consider your application design. Doing aggregations and calculations across small data sets in Java is fine, but if you're talking about producing annual reports and your data set grows large, this processing would probably be best handled by the database engine which can handle this work in a set-based method rather than row-by-row processing as happens in most applications.

Comment: Thanks so much it all makes so much sense, Loved the feedback going to work on it!